# Função javascript sendo chamada cedo demais

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Tenho um form de Cadastro que possui, dentre outros, o seguinte campo:

```
<div id="Aditivo" class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroAditivo, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroAditivo, new { @class = "form-control no-caps", @ng_readonly = "!m.Editavel" })
        </div>
```

Que só deve ser exibido quando o Modelo (outro campo do meu form de Contrato) começar com "Aditivo".

Para isso, criei a seguinte função javascript:

```
    function verificarAditivo() {
        if ($("#ModeloId_chosen").text().startsWith("Aditivo")) {
            $('#Aditivo').show();
            $('#Numero').attr('class', 'col-xs-12 col-md-2');           
        }
        else {
            $('#Aditivo').hide();
            $('#Numero').attr('class', 'col-xs-12 col-md-4');   
        }
}
```

A função verifica se o Modelo selecionado (ModeloId_chosen) começa com "Aditivo" para então exibir ou ocultar o campo criado.

Acontece que esta função também deve ser chamada assim que a página é carregada, para isso tentei usar:
`$(document).ready(verificarAditivo)` e `$(window).on("load", function () { verificarAditivo(); }`

Mas ambos não me atenderam pois, quando chamam a função, a minha lista de Modelos...:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModeloId, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModeloId, defaultSelect, new
       {
           @class = "form-control chosen-select",
           @data_url = @Url.Action("ListaModelo", "Modelo", new { modeloId = Model.ModeloId }),
           @chosen = true,
           @ng_options = "o.value as o.label group by o.group for o in options.ModeloId track by o.value",
           @onchange = "verificarAditivo(); carregaComplemento('" + @Url.Action("Listar", "Complemento", new { contratoId = Model.ContratoId }) + "?modeloId=' + this.value);",
           @ng_readonly = "!m.Editavel",
           @ng_model = "v.ModeloId",
           @chosen_scope = "m",
           @ng_change = "alterarModelo();"
       })
        </div>
    </div>
```

...ainda não foi preenchida. 
Ou seja, a função está sendo chamada cedo demais e ainda não há onde verificar se o Modelo começa com "Aditivo".

Só consegui "resolver" o problema usando um setTimeout, mas acredito que esta não seja a melhor solução.

Alguma ideia de como chamar a função que criei assim que a página estiver pronta mas com minha lista de Modelos já preenchida?

**EDIT1**: Também tentei com Angular:

```
$scope.alterarModelo = function () { verificarAditivo(); }

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () { verificarAditivo(); });
```

Comment: Olá sugiro que você dê uma olhada em promisses isso resolverá o seu problema veja este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Bs4-rqbCQc tem esta documentação da MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises se estivesse com mais tempo postava a resposta, se ninguém responder, posto a noite.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sim, se eu não conseguir aguardo sua resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei de perceber que você está usando Angular, e eu não manjo nada de Angular nem da expression language que você está usando para carregar os dados, mas vou tentar te ajudar dando um exemplo com JSVanilla e você tenta adaptar pra sua realidade, vamos lá. Primeiro você precisa saber porque esse erro acontece, diferente de outras linguagens de programação que são multi-thread() e tem por padrão processamento síncrono `(como JAVA por exemplo)`, o JS é o contrário, ele é single-thread e o processamento acontece de forma assíncrona, por isso muitas vezes você acabará caindo em erros como esse pois ele não espera o processamento de um método acabar para executar outro, antigamente se usavam callbacks encadeados para resolver este problema, mas isso era visto como má pratica pela comunidade, então por isso surgiram as `Promises`, elas basicamente são um estrutura que permite que você execute um bloco de código somente quando outro determinado finalizar o processamento, só que de maneira mais concisa facilitando a manutenção. Vamos tomar como exemplo o seguinte código:

```
let teste = 0;

function exibirValorTeste () {
    console.log(teste);
}

setTimeout (() => {
        teste = 1;
    }, 3000);

exibirValorTeste();
```

nesse código o valor exibido no console seria 0 porque o valor da variável teste só muda para 1 depois de 3 segundos, só que o método `exibirValorTeste()` é chamado antes disso, agora vamos ver o mesmo método utilizando `Promises`

```
let teste = 0;

function exibirValorTeste () {
    console.log(teste);
}

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout (() => {
        teste = 1;
        resolve();
    }, 3000)
}).then (
    (value) => {
        exibirValorTeste();
    },
  (error) => {
    //pode exibir um alerta de erro por exemplo
  }
);
```

já neste exemplo ele exibiria 1 no console pois o método `exibirValorTeste()` só é chamado quando o bloco do `setTimeout()` é finalizado, e neste momento a variável teste já estaria com o valor 1, para entendermos o funcionamento da `Promise` vamos dividi-la em duas partes:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout (() => {
        teste = 1;
        resolve();
    }, 3000)
})
```

Neste momento você está instanciando a `Promisse`, ela recebe como parâmetro uma `função anonima` em seu construtor, que por sua vez recebe 2 parâmetros, o `resolve` serve para sinalizar sucesso e o `reject` para sinalizar erro em sua `Promise`, dentro do bloco da `Promise` temos o `setTimeout()` que define que depois de 3 segundos a variável teste = 1, perceba que logo em seguida chamamos o `resolve()` isso sinaliza a `Promise` que tudo correu bem e que agora ela pode executar o bloco `then()`.

```
.then (
    (value) => {
        exibirValorTeste();
    },
  (error) => {
    //pode exibir um alerta de erro por exemplo
  }
);
```

O bloco `then()` recebe duas funções anônimas como parâmetro a primeira é executada quando você chama o `resolve()` e deve conter as ações de sucesso, e a segunda é chamada quando você chama o `reject()` e deve conter as ações de erro, `Obs: AS DUAS NUNCA SERÃO EXECUTADAS AO MESMO TEMPO`, no nosso exemplo só existe sucesso então sempre cairemos na primeira função, e dentro do bloco de sucesso chamamos a função `exibirValorTeste()`

Algumas considerações finais:

1° - O segundo parâmetro do método `then()` é opcional, se quiséssemos poderíamos escrever o `then()` só com o parâmetro de sucesso.

2° - Você pode passar valores como parâmetro as funções de sucesso e erro, ao chamar o resolve ou o reject como por exemplo `reject(algumValor)` ou `resolve(algumValor)`, e para usar esses valores é só usar os parâmetros recebido em cada respectiva função, como nossa variável teste era global isso não se fez necessário no nosso exemplo, por isso chamei o resolve() como os parenteses vazios.

recomendo que você aprofunde os estudos nas `Promises` pois este é um tópico fundamental para qualquer desenvolvedor JS.

---

Então o que você terá que fazer no seu código é fazer com que o carregamento dos seus dados esteja dentro de uma `Promise`, e o seu método de verificação esteja dentro do bloco `then()` dessa `Promise`, talvez você tenha que deixar de usar as `Expression Languages` e carregue os dados através de um requisição `AJAX`, setando os valores via JS manualmente, essa parte aí você vai ter que bater cabeça pra refatorar o seu código. Boa sorte, espero que minha explicação tenha lhe ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas explicações!

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser usado o evento `change` se for um select, para outros campos html deve procurar um evento que indique que o usuário acabou de preencher o campo, como eventos `blur` em campos de texto.

Tente alterar a opção selecionada no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('#campo-select').on('change', function() { 
     console.log('A opção selecionada foi: ' + $(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="campo-select">
  <option value="A">Opção A</option>
  <option value="B">Opção B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: tentei da seguinte forma sem sucesso:
 
$('#Modelo').on('change', function () {
    verificarAditivo();
});

Vou pesquisar algum evento que indique que o usuário acabou de preencher o campo, mas não sei se é aplicavel sendo que quando a página é carregada, já está selecionado um Modelo no campo. Quando a página já está aberta e o usuário seleciona algum Modelo, eu já consigo chamar a função usando o @onchange, o problema é chamar na hora certa quando a página acabou de ser carregada.

Comment: e se chamar no `$(document).ready` e no change?

Comment: O $(document).ready chama a função cedo demais, quando ainda não está preenchida a lista de Modelos.

Comment: E como essa lista é preenchida?

Comment: Mostrei ali no meu post, tem um Html.DropDownListFor, que recebe os dados do "ListaModelo" que é um JsonResult